# sp.check_signature cryptographic function in SmartPy

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I wanna ask about the parameters **s** and **b** in the cryptographic function:

> [sp.check_signature(k, s, b)](https://smartpy.io/demo/reference.html#_cryptography)

the second parameter **s**: is the string that we should inject in the blockchain or the signature of the value returned by the Forge operation?

the third parameter **b**: is the value returned by the Forge operation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SmartPy manual (https://smartpy.io/demo/reference.html#_cryptography) says that:

`sp.check_signature(k, s, b)`: Determine whether the signature `s` (a `sp.TSignature` value) has been produced by signing `b` (a `sp.TBytes` value) with the private key corresponding to `k` (a `sp.TKey` public key value).

It simply computes a boolean after checking that the data in 'b' has been signed by 'k' into 's'.

Comment: So we can siply use it this way:
sp.verify(sp.check_signature(params.k, params.s, params.b) == True) to evaluate the signature?

Comment: Yes. More properly, the `== True` is as always useless so: ```sp.verify(sp.check_signature(params.k, params.s, params.b))``` is typically the right way to do it.

It's used everywhere in the State Channel template https://smartpy.io/demo/index.html?template=stateChannels.py.

Comment: Thank you very much !